# Data gets overwritten on object

Tags: python, oop

Consider I have a list of names and I want to create object for those individual name in the list. The code is as follows:

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


def display(self):
    print(self.name)

names = ["john", "mike", "soniya"]

for i in range(0, len(names)):
    e = employee(names[i])

for i in range(0, len(names)):
    e.display()
```

When code executes, it only displays the last object's name instead of individual objects name. Are those objects been getting overwritten? Then what is the way to create objects using loop and store their individual data and fetching it back again?

Comment: You throw away the previous `e` on every iteration of the first loop, then call `display` on the same object every time through the second loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the objects are being overwritten. `e` only refers to the last object after the loop has completed. Try:

```
names = ["john", "mike", "soniya"]

# Use a list comprehension to create the objects and put them in a list
employees = [employee(name) for name in names]

for employee in employees:
    employee.display()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you're reassigning the same variable thrice:

```
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    e = employee(names[i])
```

If you want to store a few the objects and have access to them simultaneously, use a container, a `list`, for instance:

```
e = []

for i in range(0, len(names)):
    e.append(employee(names[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


def display(self):
    print(self.name)

names = ["john", "mike", "soniya"]
emplist=[]
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    e = employee(names[i])
    emplist.append(e)

for i in range(0, len(emplist)):
    emplist[i].display()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above I also prefer to do the following;

```
for name in names:
    employee_list.append(name)
```

So there is no need to access the names by the index.
The same goes for the printing

```
for emp in employee_list:
     emp.display()
```